# Unable to access object from controller in Rails; only accessible in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails console, when I type Thing.all, I get a list of Things. However, when I put the following into my Thing controller I get a general error (no stack trace available).

```
render :json => Thing.all
```

However, if I try the above code with a different object (e.g. "render :json => SomethingElse.all",) I get a list of SomethingElses in my browser.

What could be preventing my Things from being available for the Thing controller?

Comment: Is you model inheriting from or including an ORM? `class Human end ; Human.all` raises an error. `class Human include Mongoid::Document end ; Human.all` does not.

Comment: What is a "general error"?

Comment: It was either an internal server error or a not found error. The app puts out the same message for both.

Comment: have you tried restarting your server?